# Running cypress tests in parallel on single machine gives error

Tags: docker, parallel-processing, runtime-error, cypress, xvfb

**TLDR**: issues in running parallel cypress tests in docker containers at the same machine in jenkins.

I'm trying to run on single aws machine 2 docker instances of cypress to run different suite in parallel at the same time. I've encountered issues while seems that there's a collision on ports even though I've configured and exposed 2 unique and different ports on `docker-compose.yml` and on `cypress.json` files. he first container works but the the secnod one crashing on the error below:

```
✖  Verifying Cypress can run /home/my-user/.cache/Cypress/4.1.0/Cypress
→ Cypress Version: 4.1.0
Xvfb exited with a non zero exit code.

There was a problem spawning Xvfb.

This is likely a problem with your system, permissions, or installation of Xvfb.

----------

Error: _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)

----------

Platform: linux (Ubuntu Linux - 18.04)
Cypress Version: 4.1.0
```

**important note**: I want to implementthe parallelization on my own and not use the feature `--parallel` in cypress , I need to implement it in house on the same machine only in encapsulated environment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that this is a problem with X11 and not with Cypress. Maybe that's where the port collision is happening?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly all you need to do is to start cypress (in containers) with `xvfb-run -a`. E.g. `xvfb-run -a npx cypress run --browser Chrome`
So `-a` will assign next available port number, means you can run multiple cypress containers in parallel. Check http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless

Answer (score 1):

Note how the [documentation how Cypress uses Xvfb here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Xvfb).

In my own environment, running cypress with [verbose mode](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#Enable-Debug-Logs) like

```
DEBUG=cypress:* cypress run
```

Showed this:

```
env","DEPLOYMENT_ENV=nightly"] +0ms
  cypress:cli undefined DISPLAY environment variable +0ms
  cypress:cli Cypress will spawn its own Xvfb +1ms
  cypress:cli needs to start own Xvfb? true +0ms
  cypress:cli Starting Xvfb +0ms
  cypress:xvfb _XSERVTransSocketINETCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
  cypress:xvfb _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
  cypress:xvfb (EE)
  cypress:xvfb Fatal server error:
  cypress:xvfb (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

The key thing being that the `DISPLAY` env var is undefined - and so Cypress attempts to start its own instance of Xvfb.

But our machine already had Xvfb running, hence the error.

Solution for us is to provide the DISPLAY env var, the port is usually 99.